# Difference in size by import data vs specifying data types after load

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

More of a conceptual question.

When I import files into Python (without specifying the data types) -- just straight up `df = pd.read_csv("blah.csv/")` or `df = pd.read_excel("blah.xls")`, Python naturally guesses the data types of the columns.

No issues here.

However, sometimes when I am working with one of the columns, say, an `object` column, and I know for certain that Python guessed correctly, my `.str` functions sometimes don't work as intended, or I get an error. Yet, if I were to specify the column data type after importation as a `.str` everything works as intended.

I also noticed that if I specify one of the object columns as a `str` datatype after importation, the size of the object increases. So I am guessing Python's object type is different from a "string object" datatype? What causes this discrepancy?

Comment: First thing, how are you checking size?

Comment: I use sys.getsizeof().